# Is there event for Webhook trigger of Discord python bot library

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, webhooks

Is there an event for webhook trigger .I am trying to write a code which takes in the payload of the webhook triggered,but I am not able access custom payloads at the discord bot in on_message event

I did this code instead to access it,this works but I am looking for better methods

```
import json
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from settings import WELCOME_CHANNEL,WEBHOOK_ID_1
class NewRoleChannel(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message:discord.Message):
        if message.author == self.bot.user:
            return
        try:
            if message.webhook_id==WEBHOOK_ID_1:
                await self.handle_webhook_payload(message)
            channel = self.bot.get_channel(WELCOME_CHANNEL)
            if channel==message.channel:
                await channel.send(f'{message.author.mention} Welcome to {channel.name} channel')
        except Exception as e:
            print('exception:',e)
    
    async def handle_webhook_payload(self,message):
        try:
            obj = json.loads(message.content.replace("'", '"'))
            role_name = obj['role']
            channel_name = obj['channel'].lower().replace(' ', '-')
            
            guild = message.guild
            existing_roles = guild.roles
            existing_channels = guild.channels
            
            role_exists = any(role.name == role_name for role in existing_roles)
            channel_exists = any(channel.name == channel_name for channel in existing_channels)

            if role_exists:
                print(f"Role '{role_name}' already exists.")
            if channel_exists:
                print(f"Channel '{channel_name}' already exists.")
            if  not role_exists and not channel_exists:
                new_role = await guild.create_role(name=role_name,add_reactions=False,manage_messages=True,manage_nicknames=True,speak=False)
                new_channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name=channel_name,category=guild.categories[0],)
                await message.channel.send(f"Role '{new_role.name}' and Channel '{new_channel.name}' created!")  
                print(f"Role '{new_role.name}' and Channel '{new_channel.name}' created!")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e) 

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(NewRoleChannel(bot))
```

Comment: Have you looked at the API? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=webhook#discord.Webhook

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own webhook event:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message: discord.Message):
     if message.webhook_id is None:
         return

     self.bot.dispatch("webhook_message", message)

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_webhook_message(self, message: discord.Message):
    # your custom event that triggers whenever a webhook sends a message
```

Sadly there's no documentation for `Bot.dispatch`, but here's the [source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#L461-L499)